# xcode swift nulpad with next button not working

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am relatively new to coding so please bear with me.  I have written a simple app which has 6 text fields that need to completed before an action button is pressed to perform a mathematical calculation.

I have everything done but i can't get my next button to move to the next text field.  I have added the tool bar and the done and next button but when i press the next button the app crashes and i get a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".

I have been through the internet and I am struggling to see how do do it.  I would have thought this would be pretty straight forward.

I just can't make the next button perform the action to the next box.

Here is my code

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate  {

//IBOutlet UITextFields are here

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let fixedSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneClicked))

    let nextButton  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.textFieldShouldReturn(_:)))

    toolBar.setItems([fixedSpaceButton, nextButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true



    box1.delegate = self
    box2.delegate = self
    box3.delegate = self
    box4.delegate = self
    box5.delegate = self
    box6.delegate = self

    box1.becomeFirstResponder()


}

func doneClicked() {
    view.endEditing(true)


}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    switch textField
    {
    case box1: box2.becomeFirstResponder()
        break
    case box2: box3.becomeFirstResponder()
        break
    case box3: box4.becomeFirstResponder()
        break
    case box4: box5.becomeFirstResponder()
        break
    case box5: box6.becomeFirstResponder()
        break
    default: textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

//IBAction for maths calculations are here

I appreciate any help in advance.  I literally have no hair left.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry the Title should have been xcode swift numpad with next button not working.  I should have said for my keyboard I am using the numpad which i have set up in IB.

Comment: Please, someone must know how to make this work???